@FeignClient uses name as part of the url
I have a problem with a spring @FeignClient. I've updated one of our services to Spring Boot 3 with all corresponding libraries, so now we have open feign v4 instead of 3 previously. And it looks like it behaves differently as our tests fail now because @FeignClient sends requests using wrong url adding a value from name field to url. Here's an example:
@FeignClient(name = "my-client", url = "${my-client-api.url}")
public interface MyClient {

    @PostMapping
    MyResponse getInfo(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers,
                       @RequestBody InfoRequest infoRequest);
}

my-client-api comes from configuration, for tests it's just http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}. So, with SB2 and client v3 everything was ok, it just sent a request to the designated url. But with SB3 and client v4 it adds @FeignClient's name value to the url, i.e. it sends requests to http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}/my-client. Could anyone explain me why it happens and how to make it send requests without adding a name to a url?

Since there's no answer, I'll answer myself.
Maybe I don't fully understand how feign client works, but in case of tests a lazy attributes resolution mode helped me. In spring's manual it's written that this mode should be used for tests:
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      lazy-attributes-resolution: true

